# Code a number which is not understood by the user

Tags: vb.net, encoding, replace

I want the software to generate such number that the user will sent me and then I will understand the request of the user by just seeing the number. I will put some digit after the number such as if the user wants a ice-cream of flavor mango,then a number will be given to mango.
The number will be 
mango_digit + 8(for ice-cream). But I want to change the digits completely so that anybody cannot understand that number.

I tried with

```
Dim number As String = TextBox1.Text

    Dim Code1 As String = number.Replace("1", "2")
    Dim Code2 As String = Code1.Replace("2", "3")
    Dim Code3 As String = Code2.Replace("3", "4")
    Dim Code4 As String = Code3.Replace("4", "5")
    Dim Code5 As String = Code4.Replace("5", "6")
    Dim Code6 As String = Code5.Replace("6", "7")
    Dim Code7 As String = Code6.Replace("7", "8")
    Dim Code8 As String = Code7.Replace("8", "9")
    Dim Code9 As String = Code8.Replace("9", "0")
    Dim FINAL_CODE As String = Code9.ToLower

    MsgBox(FINAL_CODE)
```

But code doesn't work.

Any Ideas?
I want a friend too.
Thank you

Comment: Why not simply use [an encryption algorithm](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms172831.aspx) ? This has nothing but advantages on your current solution.

Comment: I think you're going to need to explain your problem more clearly. All I see is some code that seems to be intended to rotate numbers but actually just sets all characters to "0".

Comment: Think about this `123->223->333->444->555->666->777->888->999->000`.  
Now read your code again.  Keep doing this until it makes sense.

Comment: if tried in this way that u meant u will get all the number in the form of number of zeros. does ur condition decode based on zeros?

Comment: You might want to read up the Caesar Cipher

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following idea. it gives fully different number

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim number As Integer = CInt(TextBox1.Text)
    Dim l As Integer = TextBox1.Text.Length
    Dim n1 As Integer = number + NumberStyle(1, l)
    Dim n2 As Integer = number + NumberStyle(1, l)
    Dim n3 As Integer = number + NumberStyle(1, l)
    Dim n4 As Integer = number + NumberStyle(1, l)
    Dim n5 As Integer = number + NumberStyle(1, l)
    Dim n6 As Integer = number + NumberStyle(1, l)
    Dim n7 As Integer = number + NumberStyle(1, l)
    Dim n8 As Integer = number + NumberStyle(1, l)
    Dim n9 As Integer = number + NumberStyle(1, l)
    Dim d As String = CStr(n9)
    Dim Code1 As String = d.Replace("9", "2")
    Dim Code2 As String = Code1.Replace("8", "3")
    Dim Code3 As String = Code2.Replace("7", "4")
    Dim Code4 As String = Code3.Replace("6", "5")
    Dim Code5 As String = Code4.Replace("5", "6")
    Dim Code6 As String = Code5.Replace("4", "7")
    Dim Code7 As String = Code6.Replace("3", "8")
    Dim Code8 As String = Code7.Replace("2", "9")
    Dim Code9 As String = Code8.Replace("1", "0")
    Dim FINAL_CODE As String = Code9.ToLower

    MsgBox(FINAL_CODE)
End Sub

    Function NumberStyle(ByVal ip As Integer, ByVal tot As Integer)
    Dim str As String = ""
    For i As Integer = 0 To tot - 1
        str += String.Concat(ip)
    Next
    Dim res As Integer = CInt(str)
    Return res
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace vice versa, first the 9, then 8, 7, 6 ... 1. Otherwise you'll decode your previously decoded digits as well. For example if "1" turns to "2", it'll be decoded further to "3" in the next step.